# How should we handle questions that we've given up on?

Tags: discussion

I have a couple questions that I've had to reluctantly give up on due to time/work constraints.  As such, I'm not sure which of the answers to go with.  How should I handle these questions?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are under no obligation to accept any answer that you are provided with. Voting appropriately is always welcomed though.

Comment: it would be nice of we could close the questions ourselves, or at least vote to close them if we are the OP

Comment: @Purefan: I don't believe that closing a given-up question is a good idea. Maybe the asker doesn't confirm which answer is "the answer", but still knowledge is shared. Other users with the same problem may try both the solutions and find their own conclusions (then upvote their favourite question and post a comment about their experience). I'm sorry but I must disagree with your comment.

Comment: Aye. I often find answers to /my/ problem in the remains of other people's discarded answers. You can post a comment "I've given up on this problem and taken another option." if you want, though. But if you asked the question, the chances are that somebody else wants to know, too.

Answer (score 2):

You can always delete your own question if you think it is going to never be resolved.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I'm reluctant to do this as it may still be useful to other people.